# R read.table error: line 1 did not have 52 elements

Tags: r, dataframe, import, txt, read.table

I am trying to read weather data from the German Weather Service (DWD). Here is a small portion of the .txt-File:

```
KL02222200001010000101061101131101471101224  661  321 344  30 1  411  551  571  524  34 6  55 6  56 6 734 904 904 844 8941004 994 964 891 991 99116 2120 1132 21 174 81-99-99 81-99-99 81-99-99 804  001 83 43 53 11 11 12 11 01 13   061  1861   461  2261  001  001 501-9999-99999-99999
KL02222200001020000101731101631101591101654  911  241 674  15 1  321  891  621  614  31 6  67 6  53 6 764 834 834 814 984 734 884 864 981 731 87116 2116 2116 31 234 71-99-99 71-99-99 71-99-99 704 2211 73 83 83 11 11 11 01 11 13   001   001   001   001  001  001 701-9999-99999-99999
KL02222200001030000101371101211100991101194  821  581 244  52 1  651  751  641  674  51 6  55 6  49 6 784 774 774 774 814 744 804 784 811 741 80116 3120 4116 31 334 71-99-99 71-99-99 71-99-99 704  001 81 81 81 11 11 11 01 01 01   001   001   001  2461  001  0011001-9999-99999-99999
```

I try to import this file using the following code:

```r
df = read.table("myfile.txt", header=FALSE)
```

However, I receive the following error message:

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, : line 1 did not have 52 elements

I tried the first suggestion from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742227/read-table-error-in-r), but to no avail. Pasting the whole table to the read.table-option `text="..."` is impossible as the original data contains over six thousand lines.

Comment: Try reading with `sep='', strip.white=T, as.is=T`? Another option is to set `fill` to `TRUE` but that will cause more problems (introduces NAs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read.table(text="KL02222200001010000101061101131101471101224  661  321 344  30 1  411  551  571  524  34 6  55 6  56 6 734 904 904 844 8941004 994 964 891 991 99116 2120 1132 21 174 81-99-99 81-99-99 81-99-99 804  001 83 43 53 11 11 12 11 01 13   061  1861   461  2261  001  001 501-9999-99999-99999
KL02222200001020000101731101631101591101654  911  241 674  15 1  321  891  621  614  31 6  67 6  53 6 764 834 834 814 984 734 884 864 981 731 87116 2116 2116 31 234 71-99-99 71-99-99 71-99-99 704 2211 73 83 83 11 11 11 01 11 13   001   001   001   001  001  001 701-9999-99999-99999
KL02222200001030000101371101211100991101194  821  581 244  52 1  651  751  641  674  51 6  55 6  49 6 784 774 774 774 814 744 804 784 811 741 80116 3120 4116 31 334 71-99-99 71-99-99 71-99-99 704  001 81 81 81 11 11 11 01 01 01   001   001   001  2461  001  0011001-9999-99999-99999",
as.is=T, sep = "", head=F, strip.white = T, fill=T)
```

Result (converted to `tibble` for better readability)

```
 A tibble: 3 x 52
  V1           V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12
  <chr>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 KL022222~   661   321   344    30     1   411   551   571   524    34     6
2 KL022222~   911   241   674    15     1   321   891   621   614    31     6
3 KL022222~   821   581   244    52     1   651   751   641   674    51     6
# ... with 40 more variables: V13 <int>, V14 <int>, V15 <int>, V16 <int>,
#   V17 <int>, V18 <int>, V19 <int>, V20 <int>, V21 <int>, V22 <int>,
#   V23 <int>, V24 <int>, V25 <int>, V26 <int>, V27 <int>, V28 <int>,
#   V29 <int>, V30 <int>, V31 <chr>, V32 <chr>, V33 <chr>, V34 <chr>,
#   V35 <int>, V36 <int>, V37 <int>, V38 <int>, V39 <int>, V40 <int>,
#   V41 <int>, V42 <int>, V43 <int>, V44 <int>, V45 <int>, V46 <int>,
#   V47 <int>, V48 <int>, V49 <int>, V50 <int>, V51 <chr>, V52 <chr>
```

Comment: is this basically the same? read.csv("myfile.txt", header=FALSE, sep='')

Comment: @JoeErinjeri I have not tried, it may not work. The key args are `strip.white` and `as.is`